# VMware上のDebianにおいて、docker起動確認：hello-worldイメージが失敗する

Tags: docker, debian

今まで、Dockerを使ったことがなく、初めて導入しようと思います。
VMware上のDebian10で、Dockerをインストールしています。

### やりたいこと

DockerがDebian上で正常に動作していることが確認できれば良いです。

### Dockerインストール

以下の記事を参考にインストールしました。
[Docker Engine インストール（Debian 向け）](https://matsuand.github.io/docs.docker.jp.onthefly/engine/install/debian/)

[リポジトリを利用したインストール](https://matsuand.github.io/docs.docker.jp.onthefly/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-repository)

適用したバージョン：5:24.0.2-1~debian.10~buster

インストールは正常に完了したように思います。
最後に動作確認のため、hello-worldイメージを実行とあるので、以下のように実行し、エラーが表示されました。

```
~$ sudo docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.12.2:53: server misbehaving.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

エラーに記載のあるアドレス192.168.12.2からping応答はあります。

### ネットワーク設定

VMwareはネットワークをNAT接続しております。
Debian上のアドレス

```
~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:a0:35:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.12.133/24 brd 192.168.12.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute ens33
       valid_lft 1304sec preferred_lft 1304sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fea0:351d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:dd:68:e9:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ホストPC（Windows11）でのネットワーク

```
イーサネット アダプター VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
   リンクローカル IPv6 アドレス. . . . .: fe80::f7cf:65b9:aea3:2fe4%18
   IPv4 アドレス . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.79.1
   サブネット マスク . . . . . . . . . .: 255.255.255.0
   デフォルト ゲートウェイ . . . . . . .:

イーサネット アダプター VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
   リンクローカル IPv6 アドレス. . . . .: fe80::d61a:4af7:702b:2463%6
   IPv4 アドレス . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.12.1
   サブネット マスク . . . . . . . . . .: 255.255.255.0
   デフォルト ゲートウェイ . . . . . . .:
```

Comment: Windows 上で Docker を動かした方が構成がシンプルになりそうですが、敢えて VMware 上でさらに Docker を動かしている理由はありますか？

Comment: `192.168.xx.xx` はプライベートアドレスなので、ここに ping を実行してもローカル LAN 内での接続状態しか確認できません。debian 環境から外部ネットワーク (インターネット) に接続できる状態なのかを確認してみてください。(例えば apt コマンドは動作しますか？)

Comment: 外部から提供されたDockerFileがDebian(VM上で動作している)のもので、最終的にこれを動かしたいからです。

Comment: Debianの環境から、パッケージインストールできていますし、ブラウザで外部サイトも閲覧できます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"server misbehaving" で検索すると以下のようなページがヒットします。

- [dockerでsearchまたはpullした時に名前解決が出来ないエラー](https://qiita.com/tk555/items/23bb5d3d5b613a03ca2b)
- [Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47580528)

DNS サーバ指定を書き換える方法があるようです。
下記の例は `8.8.8.8` (Google Public DNS) を指定。

```bash
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search localdomain
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。/etc/resolv.confの書き換えでうまくいきました。